# Numerical approximation of differentiation

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, approximation

I have the following task to solve:

> Let $b>x$ be defined, determine $w_0,w_1$ and $w_2$ in dependency of $b$ such that the approximation
>   $f''(x) \approx w_0 f(x-h) + w_1 f(x) +w_2f(b)=D^2_{x,h}(f)$
>   is accurate for polynomials with high degree.

I did this so far:
\begin{align}
f''(x)  &\approx \frac{f'(x+\frac{h}{2})-f'(x-\frac{h}{2})}{h}\\
        &\approx \frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}}{h}\\
        &\approx \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}\\
        &\approx \frac{1}{h^2}f(x-h) - \frac{2}{h^2}f(x) + \frac{1}{h^2}f(b)
\end{align}
I'm not sure if this is the right way. But now I don't know how to go on further with $b$. I mean if $b \ne x-h$ but for example $b = x$, then the equation seems to be false.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can it also be dependent on $x$, since $x$ is needed to represent the difference between $x$ and $b$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean. In my task it says that $w_0,w_1,w_2$ depend on $b$. So when I use: $b=x-h$ then it's done, but if I chose an arbitrary b then the whole equation is not true. I now see, that I forgot that $x>b$ must be true, but still I'm confused that this equation is not true when I chose for example $b=x^2 + 1$

Comment: Why do you choose $b=x^2+1$ instead of $x+1$? But anyway, the problem asks you to derive a formula with high order of accuracy. However your formula only gives you second order. Also, you used $x+h$, instead of the assumed variable $b$.

Comment: That was just an example because $b$ is arbitrary and not given. So I tried this: $w_2 f(b)=\frac{f(z+h)}{h^2} =>$$w_2=\frac{f(z+h)}{f(b) h^2} =>$. Also this was given: $f''(x) \approx D^2_{x,h}(f)$ so this means I should end the Taylor-Series at $f''(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with Taylor expansion on each term:
$$f(x-h)=f(x)+f'(x)(-h)+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x)(-h)^2+O(h^3)\\
f(x)=f(x)\\
f(b)=f(x)+f'(x)(b-x)+\frac{1}{2!}f''(x)(b-x)^2+O((b-x)^3)$$

Then add three equations with weights $w_0,w_1,w_2$:

$$w_0f(x-h)+w_1f(x)+w_2f(b)=w_0f(x)+w_1f(x)+w_2f(x)+w_0f'(x)(-h)+w_2 f'(x)(b-x)+w_0 \frac{1}{2!}f''(x)(-h)^2 + w_2 \frac{1}{2!}f''(x)(b-x)^2+O((b-x)^3)$$

Since you want the right hand side to be $f''(x) + $ error terms, set

$$w_0+w_1+w_2=0\\
w_0(-h)+w_2(b-x)=0\\
\frac{1}{2}w_0(-h)^2+\frac{1}{2}w_2(b-x)^2=1$$

If you simplify the notation with $b=x+ah$, so $b-x=ah$, then through some algebra you can get $w_0,w_1,w_2$ in terms of $a$, and that's also in terms of $b$ and $x$.

If you plug $a=1$, which means $b=x+h$, it actually gives you the central difference formula.